# ADFS Certificate - CNG Private Key

Tags: ssl-certificate, adfs, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm attempting to setup ADFS on a Windows Server 2012 R2 box that is part of a distributed setup - 1 Domain Controller, 1 Web Front End, 1 App Server (the problem box) and 1 SQL Server box.

When attempting to configure ADFS with `Install-AdfsFarm` I get:

> “The certificates with the CNG private key are not supported. Use a
>   certificate based on a key pair generated by a legacy Cryptographic
>   Service Provider.”

The problem I have, is the **exact** same certificate is fine when collocating everything on a single box. It's just when I have separate servers the command fails.

How can a certificate be ok for `Install-AdfsFarm` on one server, but not another?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, ADFS 2012 R2 does not support CNG based certificates. Other versions do support these so that would explain why you are getting this error.

See: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/forefront/en-US/f0a93670-7912-4f55-b400-cc625d2f90f9/adfs-certificate-for-office-365?forum=ADFS

Comment: That's the strange thing, OS, .Net Framework etc are identical between the servers.
We ended up rebuilding the box and the command worked.
Our current theory is something was going wrong on certificate import. Dumping the cert via certutil showed differences between the working and failing box, despite the cert file being identical.